# What is the opposite of && in bash?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, zenity

My bash script is

```
zenity --question --text=Continue? && echo Continuing...
```

How can I make it so it would echo Stopping if the user selected no? i.e.:

```
zenity --question --text=Continue? && echo Continuing... !&& echo Stopping...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really the opposite of `&&`, but something like this might do:

```
zenity --question --text=Continue? && echo Continuing... || echo Stopping...
```

Comment: Please be cautious! If your "true"-statement isn't a simple `echo` and can return non-zero value, "else"-statement will be executed too! Please try `true && false || echo "Stopping..."`

Answer (score 3):

It's the logical OR, `||`:

```
zenity --question --text=Continue? || echo Continuing...
```

(So `true && cmd`, `false || cmd` and `cmd` all do the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `||` to create an "`OR` list":

```
zenity --question --text=Continue? && echo Continuing... || echo Stopping...
```

See http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if zenity --question --text='Continue?'
then echo Continuing...
else echo Stopping...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do it on a single line but I usually use the following which I find a bit more readable:

```
if zenity --question --text=Continue?
then
        echo Continuing...
else
        echo Stopping...
fi
```